# What is the time complexity/big-Oh notation of the function 2^(sqrt(2log(n))

Tags: algorithm, function, time-complexity, big-o

Cannot seem to figure out the time complexity of this function.

The log base is 2.

This is what I have so far...

[image: Math]

From there I have been stuck on what to do. 
Note: The upper-case X and lower-case x are the same variable. Just messed up typing the equation out.

Comment: It depends on the base of the logarithm, but I don't see any way to simplify that any further

Comment: Then what would be the big-Oh notation? Is it just O(2^(2log(n)))? It is log base 2.

Comment: Yes, I don't think it can be simplified any further, so that is your final answer

Comment: However as I said the growth rate *class* does depend on the base, so this is in fact invalid as O-notation. You must write e.g.`O(2^sqrt(2log2(n)))`

Comment: Oops, forgot the square root. Okay, if it cannot be simplified anymore then that works.
I thought I was missing something. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since 2^(log(n)) = n when the log base is two, you can get at least a rough idea of what is going on by comparing sqrt(2 log(n)) with log(n). For n large enough sqrt(2 log(n)) < log(n) so your function grows assymptotically less quickly than 2^(log(n)) = n. In fact, 2^(log(n)/k) = n^(1/k) and for large enough n sqrt(2 (log(n)) < log(n)/k for any fixed k, so your function grows assymptotically slower than n^(1/k) for any k.